# 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key .'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I got this error when i submit my form ,im confused because im using this same method on other views and it works perfectly is just on this view

heres my models

```
public class Usuario
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una cedula")]
    //[StringLength(8,MinimumLength = 8,ErrorMessage = "La cedula debe poseer 8 digitos")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un nombre")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un primer apellido")]
    public string Apellido1 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese segundo apellido")]
    public string Apellido2 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un nombre de usuario")]
    public string NombreUsuario { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una contraseña")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Contraseña { get; set; }

    public int IdRol { get; set; }

    public string Correo { get; set; }

    public int Telefono { get; set; }

    public bool Temporal { get; set; }

    public string Mensaje { get; set; }
}

public class Rol
{

    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

}
```

here is the code from the dropdownlist on the view

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Rol</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlRol", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ddlRol,"Seleccione un rol", new { @class = "control-label-col-md-2" })

        </div>
    </div>
```

Heres my controller

```
 public ActionResult Crear()
    {
        var roles = mRol.ListarRoles();
        ViewBag.ddlRol = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Nombre");
        return View();
    }
```

I got the error when i click on the submit button it says 
'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'ddlRol'.'

i already tryied the solutions from other post, but they didnt work, or i dont know if im doing something wrong pls can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: i already try those solutions but none of them work for me

Comment: What happens if you cast it to a `SelectList` instead of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("ddlRol", (SelectList)ViewBag.ddlRol,"Seleccione un rol", new { @class = "control-label-col-md-2" })
got the same error 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ddlRol'.'

Comment: Have you recompiled the project recently? That's happened to me before with this error.

Comment: every time i make a change i recompile the project  ========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Can you confirm if ViewBag.ddlRol has the correct SelectList in the controller by stepping to it with the debugger? I mostly just want to make sure it's not null.

Comment: already debugged , when i debugg it says that ViewBad.ddlRol has count 4 , and inside it has the objects i even put this on the view 
  if (ViewBag.ddlRol != null)
    {
            Html.DropDownList("ddlRol", ViewBag.ddlRol as SelectList, "Seleccione un rol", new { @class = "control-label-col-md-2" })
} and it loads correctly

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the action method you're setting the ViewBag in isn't the one for the view you're navigating to. Other than that, I'm not sure. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: already check that too :c , the problem is that if the list wasn't ok on the page load it would crash or at leats wouldnt displays the items but is ok , the problem is when i hit the submit button and it tries to take the value from the item :c , but thanks for having the time to answer me and trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Value atribute on DropDownList. In DropDownListFor you must always have text and value variables.
The better way to use @Html.DropDownListFor with SelectList.

Example: View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.YourModel, new SelectList(ViewBag.customValue, "Text", "Value"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Example: Controller

```
List<SelectListItem> listForSelect = new List<SelectListItem>();

    listForSelect.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Your text", Value = "Your value" });

    ViewBag.customValue = listForSelect;
```

Comment: as you can see in my controller i define the atributes for the value and the text:  ViewBag.ddlRol = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Nombre"); and in my view im using a html.dropdownlist not a dropdownlistfor    Html.DropDownList("ddlRol", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ddlRol,"Seleccione un rol", new { @class = "control-label-col-md-2" })

Comment: @Torake on  Html.DropDownList you have only 1 attribute, required 2(text, value);

Comment: @Torake 1 is used to display value in html and second to parse data to model

Comment: i have  ViewBag.ddlRol = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Nombre");
where "Id" is the value and " Nombre" is the text and "roles" the items

Comment: @Torake check HTMLDROPDOWN again - only 1 attribute there. You have problem in View not in Controller.

Comment: im checking the documentation and already tryied on view , but there is no suitable constructor for those parameters 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist(v=vs.111).aspx idk if im wrong

Comment: @Torake I might be wrong, but DropDownList(String, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, IDictionary<String, Object>) may be this.
Also try my solution and everythings will work OK).

Comment: how can i pass an IDictionary to the view using the viewbag i tried    IDictionary dic = new Dictionary<int,string>();
            foreach (Rol rol in Mapper.Map<List<Models.Rol>>(roles)) {
                dic.Add(rol.Id, rol.Nombre);
            }
            ViewBag.Diccionario = dic;
and on my view  @Html.DropDownList("ddlRol", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ddlRol, "Seleccione un rol",ViewBag.Diccionario, new { @class = "control-label-col-md-2" })
but it says dropdown list only takes 5 overloads